# Not able to update AppSettings for Azure App Service using PS cmdlet Set-AzWebApp

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

This seems like a fairly simple task to do and I have numerous other examples where people have implemented it in the similar fashion. But somehow this doesnt work for me. Here is my script.

```
$webapp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupName
$appset = $webapp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$appset


$newsettings = new-object Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair
$newsettings.Name = "keyName"
$newsettings.Value = "MyValue"
   
$appset.Add($newsettings)
   
$newappset = @{}
$appset | ForEach-Object {
    $newappset[$_.Name] = $_.Value
}

Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupName -Name $webappname  -AppSettings $newappset
$webapp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupName

Write-Output "New AppSettings:"
$webapp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
```

Both before/after gives the same set of configs and nothing changes when I check it on the Azure portal. I don't get any errors as well.
Can anyone see what's wrong with the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a reported issue here.

Reference : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/15078

[image]

[image]

I am able to observe the behavior at my end despite using a older Az module  4.2.0. You could try downgrading further and give it a shot.

Alternatively as a **workaround**, I was able to meet my requirement using the management API.

```
function update-webappsetting($web,$appsetting)
{
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken).Token 
$url = "https://management.azure.com" + $web.Id + "/config/appsettings?api-version=2020-06-01"
$headers = @{"Content-type"="application/json";"Authorization" = "Bearer $token"}
$body = '{"properties" :' + ($appsetting | ConvertTo-Json)  +  '}'


Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method PUT
}
```

To invoke the function :

```
update-webappsetting -web $web -appsetting $newappset
```

Does the exact thing that `Set-AzWebApp -Name NAME -ResourceGroupName RG -AppSettings SETTING` does

Comment: Ill check that out, but whats that link that you have attached, looks like a phishing attack website.

Comment: I guess, I had a typo when copy and pasted, it is a github url. Issue:15078. @Alex thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Just to add there is a fix in progress. refer : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/14998

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Satya's response, another workaround is to pass along other `SiteConfig` properties like `-HttpLoggingEnabled $true` as mentioned in [#15038](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/15038#issuecomment-843612008):

```
Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupName -Name $webappname -AppSettings $newappset -HttpLoggingEnabled $true
```

However, the fix for this issue has now been rolled out and is available as part of the latest `Az` module versioned `6.0.0` having `Az.Websites` version `2.6.0`. I can confirm that your script works alright with the latest `Az` module.

Please update the module on your machine with:

```
Update-Module -Name Az
```

and retry setting AppSettings.